# Multi-line Links with preg_replace | PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

If someone posts a multi-line post that contained text and links, I want to be able to find and wrap the links with `<p>` tags, but I can only do it with one link at a time (source code comes from phpBB2 - clickable links function), which causes every link to be like this:

```
<p>http://www.bbc.co.uk/</p>
<p>http://www.bbc.co.uk/</p>
<p>http://www.bbc.co.uk/</p>
```

Where I want it to happen to be like this:

```
<p>http://www.bbc.co.uk/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/</p>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feed it to DOM [loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) function and [getElementsByTagName('p')](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), make a reference with `->item(i)` based on the `->length`, get the `nodeValue` and just make a new paragraph with [document.createElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php), set the nodeValue to your string of `nodeValue`s that you retrieved from the loop after concatenating them with `\n<br>` or something.

You shouldn't use regex for this.

Comment: Why? Why shouldn't I use regex for this?

Comment: So many reasons. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Essentially, HTML isn't a regular language, so regex doesn't have the power to fully and properly parse it. There are cases where regex can help you munge HTML, but it's rarely the right tool for the job.